# ZERO-RESULT when passing lat-long of USA in place api

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Google place API :

friends, Is anyone know what is the lat long for USA to add in Google place API,
as I want to get all the addresses of McDonald's(or any other business) of
entire USA for that I need to pass lat-long of USA in Place API, but when I pass lat-long
for USA in API,its giving ZERO-RESULT,
and same API is working perfectly and giving exact result when I pass lat-long
of any state of USA.what is the solution to this.? If anyone has used it,

Please suggest..!!
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

The Places Library's [Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests) doesn't take a `LatLng`, it takes a `LatLngBounds` - that is a bounding rectangle. Provide a `LatLngBounds` that encompasses the continental United States (or whatever region you want) and it should work.

What `LatLngBounds` values are you using?

Comment: actually i am using following api script..$geocode=file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=40.4230,98.7372 W&radius=50000&name=McDonald\'s&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyDFhkgtDZVQF42iHamFBnZOH3z36zrG9Fw'); and I want to get list of (may be not all but random 10-15)addresses of mcDonald's or any other businessof entire USA user types in text box ...so how can i get it..plz help..

Answer (score 0):

The Places API will not return all the McDonalds in the USA.  It returns either up to 60 results (20 at a time) or RadarSearch will return up to 200 places at once (but with less detail, and at a 10x cost multiplier).  If you just give it the coordinates returned by geocoding the USA [United States (37.09024, -95.712891)], which is somewhere in Kansas, depending on which part of the service you call (Nearby Search, TextSearch or RadarSearch), you might or might not get the results you expect.

However [using USA and searching for McDonald with the Places Library in the Google Maps API v3](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_10minuteDriveG.html?address=USA&q=McDonalds), does give me results.  You must be doing something else in your request to cause the ZERO_RESULTS.

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchPaging):

- By default, each Nearby Search or Text Search returns up to 20 establishment results per query; however, each search can return as many as 60 results, split across three pages.

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#RadarSearchRequests)

- The Google Places API Radar Search Service allows you to search for up to 200 Places at once, but with less detail than is typically returned from a Text Search or Nearby Search request.
- Radar Search shares the same [usage limits](https://developers.google.com/places/policies#usage_limits) and quota as Text Search and Nearby Search; however, the Radar Search Service is subject to a five times multiplier. That is, each Radar Search request that you make will count as 5 requests against your quota

Comment: yes if i pass 37.09024, -95.712891 lat-long then it only gives mcD braches of Kansas only as its lat-long f kansas ..can i please get the api script of the [link]using USA and searching for McDonald with the Places Library in the Google Maps API v3,because that what i want..whatevr business name(ex. MacDonald's)user enters in textbox,he should get addresses of that name in USA only..and can i get 10-15 random addresses from entire usa on McD..?? thanks..

Comment: and actually i need to apply exacly what google map does.When I start typing McDonalds ,as i type it shows addresses below in list in textbox of mcD..as it continue typing related addresses come in list under textbox..is it possible to do the same using google place api??  ...

Comment: You mean [autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete)?

Comment: yes exactly,its what i wanted...but can i show only US Addresses only when i type..?? no other country addresses should show in list.. and if yes then how?..